# Yet another in app purchase - Restore Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am implementing restore purchases in my app. my app consists of Non-Consumable items.

I have placed one button like "Restore your previous purchases".On tap of that button, I am calling a function.

This is the code I have included for restoring the purchase.

```
-(void)restorePurchases
{    
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Is this enough, or do I need to include anything else to restore the previous transaction?

Comment: have you implemented all the methods other than restore part

Comment: @VimalVenugopalan:yes. i have done the purchase part.and now implemnting restore part

Answer (score 0):

The best blog I found on restore functionality and which I used to do it in my application is
[Restore In App Purchase](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/To-restore-the-previously-done-transactions-in-InApp-purchase-in-iPhone--1412.php)

Comment: when i added the below code nothing happens -(void)restorePurchases{
    
  NSLog(@"restore purchase");
    
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    
    
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

Comment: Above link does not existing now.

Answer (score 0):

You are done resubmit to apple now.